# How to validate user content on real time with ckeditor's accessibility checker?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am new in using ckeditor and its API. I would like to find a way to validate the content of the users through the accessibility checker while they are typing.
The information available in the documentation do not make clear how to do this.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this...

```
<script>
      var instance = CKEDITOR.replace('editorck');
      instance.on('focus', function(event) {
             var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editorck'];
             if(editor.plugins.a11ychecker){
                 var a11ycheckerCommand = new CKEDITOR.command(editor, {
                        exec: function( editor ) {
                                 editor.execCommand("a11ychecker");
                              }
                        });
                        a11ycheckerCommand.setState(CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_ON);
                        a11ycheckerCommand.exec(editor);
                  }
       });
      instance.on('key', function (event) {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances['editorck'];
        editor.execCommand("a11ychecker.listen");          
      });
</script>
```

The code above expects two events. The first is the "onfocus" which activate the accessibility checker when the editor area is focused. The second is what I'm looking for, call some command or execute something to validate the content while keyup event is occuring.

The next step is to allow the user to save the content if it is validated. Perhaps a way to get the current accessibility issues list?

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.a11ychecker.IssueList or editor.plugins.a11ychecker.IssueList ?
```